# MediaPlayer error android

Tags: android, media-player

I have an activity which has a series of buttons which when pressed should play an audio file. I have been trying to implement this using MediaPlayer however I cant get it to work.
Here is the code I have been trying:

```
     final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Button ger1play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ger1play);ger1play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          mp.setDataSource(this, R.raw.greet_1);
          mp.prepare();
          mp.start();

      }
  });
```

The setDateSource method doesnt seem to work, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
I would like to then set the mediaPlayer to the relevant audio file based on which button is pressed, is this possible?

**Updated**

```
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Button ger1play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ger1play);ger1play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
                        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(R.raw.greet_1);

                       mp.setDataSource(GreetingsLesson.this, R.raw.greet_1);

                       mp.prepare();

                       mp.start();

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                       e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                       e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                       e.printStackTrace();

                    }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Button ger1play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ger1play);ger1play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
  try {

                     mp.setDataSource(CurrentActivity.this, R.raw.greet_1);

                     mp.prepare();

                     mp.start();

                  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();

                  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();

                  } catch (IOException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();

                  }
     }
  });
```

Comment: When I tried this Eclipse still give me an error and it suggests changing type of greet_1 to Uri?

Comment: make sure loaction of raw is `res/raw/` and u are using `mp.setDataSource(CurrentActivity.this, R.raw.greet_1);`

Comment: if it's saying change type to Uri then use `Uri myUri = Uri.parse(R.raw.greet_1)`

Comment: Doing this gives an error that says "change type greet_1 to String"?

Comment: `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.greet_1);
Button ger1play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ger1play);ger1play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
  try {
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
}` update your code

Comment: Ok this worked when I took out the mp.prepare();
Thank you very much for your help.
One more thing, rather than creating a new mediaplayer for each audio file (there is 20 of them), how can I just pass another audio file to this mediaplayer, in each onClickLister

Comment: I update my code to match yours but I get an error `"prepareAsync called in state 8"` but I do not hear any sound.

Answer (score 0):

Ifyou want to send the media player object with one of the files fromapplication raw resources or from application assets files you can dothat as follows:

```
try {
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResouceFd(R.raw.greet_1);
mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
mp.start();
fd.close();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// handle exception
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
// handle exception
}
```

Comment: 04-26 15:08:26.326: E/MediaPlayer(528): attachNewPlayer called in state 8
04-26 15:08:26.326: W/System.err(528): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-26 15:08:26.326: W/System.err(528):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)

This is what happens when clicking the buttons after adding the code

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.greet_1);
```

Then you don't need the prepare or start.

Comment: This doesn't work as it says "The final local variable mp cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"
Still struggling to get this working

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in an emulator?  If so check your AVD manager has under hardware, the property  "Audio playback support | yes" added